# Wrapper over Hive QL / UDFs / Impala Queries

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I am trying to write a wrapper that could easily be used by people coming from the Sql background. I have not started on this work yet and I would like to know what approach should I take.

Here's the problem statement - If someone has a lot of native Sql written on their rdbms data and they want to switch to hadoop then there are lots of problems. A major problem of building  tables in hdfs has been eliminated by Hive. Now comes the querying part - for this we have different frameworks but none is complete in itself - like one might be slow and other might be lacking in features. For example, there's Impala, there's Hive QL but then for the end user there is no ONE framework. 
I intend to do something like this - select(comma-separated string of column names, tableName).where(filter-expression)....

Something like Linq for hdfs and underneath it would figure out what's the best way to execute select(hive ql or Impala), best way to do a where clause, etc.

Suggestions? Ideas? Critique?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [ODBC](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/ImpalaBeta/0.7/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_topic_2_7.html) or [JDBC](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/ImpalaBeta/0.7/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_topic_2_8.html) drivers for Impala? These drivers are used by third-party tools like MicroStrategy or Tableau to submit queries to Impala.